# Automatic onload, and periodic, save

Tags: cognito-forms

I would like to save a form the moment it loads and continue to automatically save it every few seconds. NOTE: it should be saved as an entry in the form's database - not locally!

Is this possible?

I imagine that this would essentially be like replicating the "Save button"'s save functionality.

The reason for all this is because the form gets prefilled with some data, including user information such as email. This information/form should be saved and shared with the user right away, *not* after the user press save or submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for support for Cognito Forms.  We don't have that feature; the Save and Resume feature is available but it does require the user to manually press the Save button.